# how to modify a value in a comumn in a table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, find-replace

I have a table MYTABLE in a database with several columns.

a given column DOGCOLORS is valued in all rows with multiple values:

1: yellowredgreen
2: redpurplegreen
3: blackgreengray

I am trying to find a query that updates the value "green" with vaue "orange" in every value of the column DOGCOLORS in table MYTABLE

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE MYTABLE
  SET DOGCOLORS=REPLACE(DOGCOLORS,'red','orange');
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

the result should be something like:

1: yellowredorange
2: redpurpleorange
3: blackorangegray

the query im running on DBeaver gives those errors:
PL/SQL: ORA-02185: a token other than WORK follows COMMIT
Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

;

any help appreciated

Comment: You are reading the wrong manual. The Oracle SQL Reference Guide is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2). I don't know where you found `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, though. What is it meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` with `COMMIT;`.
Also you don't need 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' it starts automatically

Answer (score 1):

To update every substring  "green" with vaue "orange"  in *plain SQL* use this query

```
update MYTABLE
set dogcolors = replace(dogcolors,'green','orange')
where dogcolors like '%green%'
;
commit;
```

To call an anonymous PL/SQL block use

```
BEGIN
update MYTABLE
set dogcolors = replace(dogcolors,'green','orange2')
where dogcolors like '%green%'
;
commit;
END;
/
```

Note a good practice is to limit the updated row and exclude the rows that would be updated to the *same value* - see the WHERE predicate in the UPDATE statement.

To commit transaction you typically use only `commit;`, but if you need it a bit *more verbose* this is also a [legal syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2) (though used very rarely):

```
 commit work comment 'transaction';
```